# Как организовать ввод в определенное поле на с++

Tags: c++

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на клавишу в определенное поле, например в строку в браузере вводились какие нибудь числа. Как можно организовать этот ввод на с++?

Comment: Вы хотите связать браузер со своей программой на С++?

Comment: @avp, не обязательно браузер можно любую программу в которой есть поля для ввода данных.

Comment: Если вы хотите *использовать* эти данные в программе на С++, то может быть проще организовать [GUI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) непосредственно в ней